# Wifi router with DHCP enabled to a network

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have this very cheap all in one machine (modem + wifi router) provided by my service provider. I have disabled the wifi on it and bought a netgear nighthawk. Now i am trying to set it up that some devices are connected to wifi and some are connected using wire to the modem. I am trying to figure out how i can have DHCP enabled on both machine and also have access to machines connected to modem. So my setup is as follow.

Modem has 4 LAN ports and have 3 devices and the the nighthawk wifi router connected to it. The access IP of the modem is 192.168.1.1 and starting IP is 192.168.1.2 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and have DHCP enabled to provide IPs to everything connected to it.
The WIFI router access IP is IP 192.168.0.1 has starting IP 192.168.0.2 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and DHCP enabled to provide IP to everything connected to it.
I would like devices connected to WIFI router to have access to devices connected to Modem and vice versa.

Can someone help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your configuration you have 2 NAT one from the ISP and another one from your access point/router (nighthawk). Meaning that you have 2 networks with different IP ranges.

This is how I configure the LAN when I have multiple routers to extend the coverage.

1. Assign an IP address to the nighthawk on the range of 192.168.1.x/255.255.255.0 ex 192.168.1.2
2. Disable the DHCP on the nighthawk
3. Connect your ISP router to a **LAN** interface on the Nighthawk.

What will happen is that your nighthawk will be just an access point, all the DHCP will be at the ISP router meaning that all ips will be on the same range. If you connect your ISP to the Nighthawk WAN interface it is going to go nowhere because some of them are programmed to do a NAT between the Lan an Wan interfaces.

I also configure the DHCP to assign ip's from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.200 range, all devices from 1 to 99 are routers, access points, servers, cameras, printers or devices that need an static ip address. Then I have segments ex. routers are 1-9, printers 10-29, etc etc. By doing this I will now what device is or their purpose on the network.

Hope it helps.